# Log4j Warning after removing log4j related files

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I am trying to run a mvc sample code in my machine. I have commented all the Log4j imports and commented all the logger statements in code. But still am getting warning in the console. I have removed the resources folder which contains log4j.properties.

```
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/bin/server;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/bin;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;;C:\Riya\software_downloads\eclipse;;.
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:49 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GeneratingBills' did not find a matching property.
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 448 ms
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 26, 2014 8:03:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6088 ms
```

Comment: did you update your war file in tomcat ? if not please update and check it .Lets know

Comment: Did you delete correct files, please double check...

Comment: You might have commented in your code, but not in org.springframework.web.contex. Its complaining for Spring not on your code. Its just a warning. (If you want the logs for spring you could add a log4j.properties which could give useful logs on spring.)

Comment: I havent generated war file...I am trying to run the code by run->run on server. I am new to java/j2ee so first am trying to run with the run option run on server without generating any war file, just checking the output in the console and browser. @Gk

Comment: @Jay - Previously,I tried run with log4j.properties and logger statements in the code, since m getting the warning related to log4j, I have removed and tried to run the code. So what I have to check in org.springframework.web.context? Its just a warning but am not able to proceed after this.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want any logging you could safely ignore that WARN message, it only states there is no log4j configuration done.

If you problem is only the below warning,

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Add a log4j.properties and add the below single line, it will not show the warning and would switch off all the logging.

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
```

Comment: yes, I have included this line but stills shows the same warning.

Comment: the warning got removed.It got reflected now. Thanks